# JsonApiDotNetCore and SignalR implementation

Tags: c#, .net-core, json-api

I'm using the JsonApiDotNetCore library, and I'm trying to push data through SignalR to the clients.
Pushing the data is no problem, however, I want to be this data formatted according to the JSON:API specs. As the JsonApiDotNetcore library already does this for general API calls, I'm trying to do the same for the SignalR messages.

I tried to access the `IJsonApiOptions`, and use the SerializerOptions of it to serialize my data. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.
Also not when I add a `ResourceObjectConverter` to it myself.

Is there any option to do this?

We are currently running on v5.0.3, as of problems on the front-end application which needs a lot of rewrites if we update it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself, by using a special converter.
I've created a `ICustomResponseModelAdapter` which uses objects from the library itself, see below the implementation.
It's not fully JSON:API format, as we are triggering also some other entities in an endpoint for other entities (For example if Group is changed, it's possible we send an event for a User also)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Configuration;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Middleware;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Queries.Internal;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.QueryStrings;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Resources;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Serialization.Objects;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Serialization.Response;

namespace xxx.Api.SignalR
{
    public class CustomResponseModelAdapter : ResponseModelAdapter, ICustomResponseModelAdapter
    {
        private readonly IJsonApiRequest _request;
        private readonly IJsonApiOptions _options;
        private readonly ILinkBuilder _linkBuilder;
        private readonly IMetaBuilder _metaBuilder;
        private readonly IResourceDefinitionAccessor _resourceDefinitionAccessor;
        private readonly IEvaluatedIncludeCache _evaluatedIncludeCache;
        private readonly IRequestQueryStringAccessor _requestQueryStringAccessor;
        private readonly ISparseFieldSetCache _sparseFieldSetCache;
        private readonly IResourceGraph _resourceGraph;

        public CustomResponseModelAdapter(IJsonApiRequest request, IJsonApiOptions options, ILinkBuilder linkBuilder, IMetaBuilder metaBuilder, IResourceDefinitionAccessor resourceDefinitionAccessor, IEvaluatedIncludeCache evaluatedIncludeCache, ISparseFieldSetCache sparseFieldSetCache, IRequestQueryStringAccessor requestQueryStringAccessor, IResourceGraph resourceGraph) : base(request, options, linkBuilder, metaBuilder, resourceDefinitionAccessor, evaluatedIncludeCache, sparseFieldSetCache, requestQueryStringAccessor)
        {
            _resourceGraph = resourceGraph;

            _request = request;
            _options = options;
            _linkBuilder = linkBuilder;
            _metaBuilder = metaBuilder;
            _resourceDefinitionAccessor = resourceDefinitionAccessor;
            _evaluatedIncludeCache = evaluatedIncludeCache;
            _sparseFieldSetCache = sparseFieldSetCache;
            _requestQueryStringAccessor = requestQueryStringAccessor;
        }

        public Document ConvertSpecific(object model)
        {
            _sparseFieldSetCache.Reset();

            Document document = new Document();

            Action<ResourceObject, ResourceType, IIdentifiable> addRelations = (ResourceObject resourceObject, ResourceType resourceType, IIdentifiable resource) =>
            {
                foreach (JsonApiDotNetCore.Resources.Annotations.RelationshipAttribute relation in resourceType.Relationships)
                {
                    resourceObject.Relationships ??= new Dictionary<string, RelationshipObject?>();
                    resourceObject.Relationships.Add(relation.PublicName, new RelationshipObject
                    {
                        Links = _linkBuilder.GetRelationshipLinks(relation, resource),
                        Data = default
                    });
                }
            };

            if (model is IEnumerable<IIdentifiable> resources)
            {
                ResourceType resourceType = null;

                List<ResourceObject> resourceObjects = new List<ResourceObject>();
                foreach (IIdentifiable resource in resources)
                {
                    if (resourceType == null)
                        resourceType = _resourceGraph.GetResourceType(resource.GetType());
                    ResourceObject resourceObject = ConvertResource(resource, resourceType, EndpointKind.Primary);

                    // Add relationships
                    addRelations(resourceObject, resourceType, resource);

                    // Add to results
                    resourceObjects.Add(resourceObject);
                }

                // Add to document
                document.Data = new SingleOrManyData<ResourceObject>(resourceObjects);
            }
            else if (model is IIdentifiable resource)
            {
                ResourceType resourceType = _resourceGraph.GetResourceType(model.GetType());

                ResourceObject resourceObject = ConvertResource(resource, resourceType, EndpointKind.Primary);
                // Add relationships
                addRelations(resourceObject, resourceType, resource);

                // Add to document
                document.Data = new SingleOrManyData<ResourceObject>(resourceObject);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Data being returned must be resources, operations, errors or null.");
            }

            document.JsonApi = GetApiObject();
            document.Links = _linkBuilder.GetTopLevelLinks();
            document.Meta = _metaBuilder.Build();

            return document;
        }
    }
}
```